# Как конвертировать дамп базы mysql в postgresql?

Tags: mysql, sql, postgresql

Есть файл **dump.sql**
Он предназначен для MySQL

```
MySQL dump 10.13  Distrib 5.7.20, for Win64 (x86_64)
```

БД в кодировке cp1251
Ошибка при обычном восстановлении `psql databasename < /path/to/dump/dump.sql` такая

```
ERROR:  invalid byte sequence for encoding "UTF8": 0xd3 0xc0
```

Нужно конвертировать его таким образом, чтобы его можно было восстановить в postgresql.
Есть какие-то плагины? или способы?

Comment: А перевести psql на cp1251 (как это описано в документации, правда. там показано для 1252, но суть-то та же) - не?

Comment: не могли бы вы дать ссылку, спасибо

Comment: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.2/static/app-psql.html. См. раздел `Notes for Windows Users`. И не забудьте, что соединение с БД и поля таблиц тоже должны быть CP1251...

Comment: dump.sql — это же обычный текстовый файл, не? почему просто не перегнать его в utf-8?

Comment: Согласен с @Fat-Zer: когда была нужда в таком преобразовании, просто отконвертировал Far Manager'ом через клипбоард.

Comment: Теперь при дампе его смущает `

Comment: дык просто удали или замени на обычные двойные кавычки... если файл небольшой(порядка мегабайт), то любым текстовым редактором... если большой, то на *никсах это делается sed'ом...

Comment: спасибо попробую `sed`